# TryCast(row.FindControl) not working for updating record

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have been working on this already for hours but no result. Here is my code:

```vb
Dim first_name As String = (TryCast(row.FindControl("txtfirst_name"), TextBox)).Text
Dim last_name As String = (TryCast(row.FindControl("txtlast_name"), TextBox)).Text
Dim birth_date As DateTime = (TryCast(row.FindControl("txtbirth_date"), TextBox)).Text
Dim gender As String = (TryCast(row.FindControl("txtgender"), TextBox)).Text
```

And here my items in the gridview for the textboxes and labels

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblfirst_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>'></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtfirst_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("first_name") %>' Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lbllast_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("last_name") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtlast_name" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("last_name") %>' Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Birthday" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblbirth_date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("birth_date") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtbirth_date" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("birth_date") %>' Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblgender" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtgender" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("gender") %>' Width="140"></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm using this to update gridview in ASP.NET. I have already entered new values in the textboxes but the code above still returns the old value. Please help!

Comment: Please add some more code with question .. especially your Page_load event code so as I think you changing your textbox values in page load event..

Comment: There is nothing on my page load but only the session function.

Comment: OK but we can't identify your issue using just 4-5 lines of code

Comment: My question is when I am in the gridview and click the edit button. All the textboxes are enabled. That is when I can update the data. But after I click the update button. But the code does not follow the values that are inputted in the textboxes. It still returns the original value not the edited one.

Comment: when you binding your Gridview control ?

Comment: Not yet binding. Just updating